# HTML Page with GWT

Tags: gwt

is it possible to have parts (instead of the entire page) of an HTML page written with GWT?
Is it usual?

I'm quite new to GWT and trying to understand the workflow of it.

Thanks.

Comment: I was reding my question now and maybe it is not clear enough. I meant HTML static pages, written by hand (or any other means) and on these pages have parts (forms, media, whatever...) in GWT. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I meant HTML static pages, written by hand (or any other means) and on these pages have parts (forms, media, whatever...) in GWT.

Yes, the simplest way this can be achieved is setting an id attribute on the elements you want to be filled in by GWT, e.g.

```html
<body>
  <div>
    ...
    <div id="myId"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

, and then using

```java
RootPanel myIdPanel = RootPanel.get("myId");
```

so you can put any GWT contents into myIdPanel.

Note, that there are many more ways to mix HTML that's generated by GWT and by other means - basically any combination is possible.

Comment: Thanks very much! That's what I wanted to know. Just one doubt. Is it an usual approach? I mean, do developers usually do this and if yes, why? What would they like to achieve by having GWT and pre-coded HTML? Just to make sure if my idea isn't something from another world. Thanks

Comment: It's all being used in real world sites. There are 100% consequent applications that render everything within the body tag by GWT and never leave the page. Others have e.g. a header and footer that's shared with other non-GWT pages, so it's often static or maybe generated by a JSP/PHP/... script. And there are even pages that are mostly generated on the server side, and contain just a few little GWT widgets. So it's best to analyze the requirements, and not be limited by the technology (and that's why I like GWT).

Comment: A couple examples: the header part of https://groups.google.com/forum/ comes from the HTML, animated with JS; GWT _injects_ the search box into the header and puts the application at the end of the `RootPanel.get()`. http://www.gwtproject.org on the other hand is all statically generated, and GWT comes as progressive enhancement (collapsible tree view, loads pages in AJAX and switches the URL using HTML5 `pushState`). That approach allows the web site to be indexed by search engines.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out their UIBinder approach:
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html

Comment: You'll notice that you can declare sections as being HTML, and then add the custom pieces you want.  (you can always had in arbitrary HTML from java too, though potentially less clean).